# How to distribute Android device for my customers so they don't need to create Google accounts?

Tags: google-account, customization, accounts

I'm seeking a solution for the distribution of my Android-based devices (tablets) to end-users. I have a tablet with a custom Android 11 OS, and I've developed an application that is publicly available on the Google Play store.

In the future, I plan to sell these tablets to my customers. The challenge I'm facing is that I'd like to avoid a situation in which **they** need to create individual Google accounts (some of them might not have their own Google account or might not be technically capable of creating one).

I haven't found a feasible solution to this issue yet. I considered using something like 'zero-touch enrollment,' but if I understand it correctly, it's more geared towards IT administration, and I would need to have an authorized manufacturer that supports this feature.

Another solution I'm contemplating (not sure if it exists, though) is customizing the OS in a way that it automatically starts my application on startup. However, I'm uncertain if I would need my own CDN for software updates, etc. I'm not sure if such a thing is even possible.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: IMHO creating Google accounts for your customers is not an option. Google has made it very difficult to create new accounts. Usually you have to enter a cellular number for verification and that number is burnt after creating 3-5 accounts. How and if you are providing updates to your pre-installed apps is nothing we can help you with, you simply have to decide which way to go. Not that questions about writing ROMs are considered off-topic here as we focus on Android from user perspective.

Comment: How does the tablet's customised OS relate to your app? Is it required, or just helpful? How are you going to set up tablets with the customised OS to sell? Flashing them by hand will be very slow work.

Comment: If your customers need to get your app through the Google Play store, they will have to have a Google account regardless of the state of the tablet.

If you create your custom Android OS build to bypass the initial setup and only run your app, this could be accomplished, but you would need to find other solutions for updating the app/OS in the future.

Comment: @Robert yes, this is the issue with creating accounts for your customers (cellular number is only one of the issues...).

Comment: @JohnDallman the factory flashes tablets with chosen Android version (I probably misused the 'customized' word here - it is just a clean Android 11 from one of the release branches).

Comment: @jlehenbauer Ok so this seems like I would need to have access to the Android sources to build my own distribution from scratch for this particular tablet. Unfortunately this is probably not possible since I won't get the device configuration files for the build system...

Comment: @pion3k: OK, that's not "customised" except in the sense of "customised for the specific hardware." Why Android 11? It's almost certainly going to stop getting security patches early in 2024. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Overview).

Comment: @JohnDallman Frankly speaking, it is the latest version offered by the tablet manufacturer. I could inquire about a newer version, but when I requested an older one, they were already complaining that I couldn't switch easily (or downgrade) to Android 10, for example, because it has a 'different PCB,' and in such a case, I'd need to order another tablet suited for Android 10. So I am not sure if this is applicable for Android 12 or newer.

Comment: @pion3k: If the customers find they're falling victim to security vulnerabilities, and you've supplied the tablets, they're going to take it out on you. Does your agreement with the tablet manufacturer cover security patches and updates to later versions of Android? If not, you've got a serious risk ahead.

Answer (score -1):

If nothing else works and you want to supply the tablets, you could create just one Google account for this purpose.

- Give it a suitable name such as "myapplicationname registration".
- Disable all syncing on the tablets
- Disable all syncing on the accounts from a browser

One is allowed to have multiple accounts on a device, so the end user can still create their own account `instead of`/`in addition to`.

Comment: Thanks @rohit-gupta it seems like one of the options. However I am afraid that it creates a potential problems with Google applications that the users may use on the 'shared' account (such as sharing the same gmail account, google drive etc.).